# How many page can i crawl in one hour using multithread in c# programming with sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, web-crawler

I have a project which is about crawling a e commerce site which has nearly 15 thousands of products and i couldn't count but nearly 25 thousands of page.I wrote a program for that in c# using multithreading, totaly i used 20 thread.But there is no high performanse when i used just 5 thread.Am i thinking wrong ? couldn't it be increased while crawling ?

I test that i crawl 500 page and take their html to db in ten minustes.Is it normal ? or can i increase it ?

Moreover SQL server is ok for 20 thread concurrent insert, update operations, but when i increase that thread number to 100 thread, will i face a problem ?

I calculate totally site process will take 5 hours with 10 thread .. I need help to decrease this period .. or it is normal .. I don't want to use more computer ...

My pc details are 2 GB RAM, 1.87 GHz intel t2130...

---

I checked my CPU is %90 , I crawl the site from internet, my ram is %75 and each second while program is running, i take 70 kb per/second. How can increase crawling speed ?

Comment: Too many variables to answer this reliably. WebRequests are limited to (I think) 6 concurrent per domain. Probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you crawling the site over the internet? If so, how fast is your internet connection.  Check your task manager. If your CPU is maxed out, you need to get a faster machine or make your algorithms for parsing the pages more efficient.  If your CPU isn't doing anything you probably need a faster connection.  Also, If you are crawling the site over the internet, I believe there's a maximum number of requests to 1 domain restriction, which (I think) is by default set to 2, but this can be changed. Also, ensure that if this isn't your site that you obey the robots.txt file to ensure they don't block you.   Perhaps the site itself is throttling you because of the amount of traffic they detect.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the biggest problem you will challenge is not your environment but the fact that the other site is going to block you if you are going to crawl too fast.

If your sql server does not cope, you can always write the html to file first and later, on your own pace, import that into the DB. This also gives you the option to change your crawling code if it turns out the html has changed.

strong advice: DO NOT CRAWL AT HIGH SPEED this will get the other site in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of threads above the number of logical cores doesn't make much sense. You won't see any benefit if 4 threads are working, and other 96 are queued.

Additionally, you should profile to see where actual bottlenecks are. Network latency might account more than raw processing if there is little data to process on each page. Profiling might also reveal that your algorithm needs to be improved.

So forget about multiplying your threads indefinitely and profile. [EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/) provides a free .NET profiler you can use, for example.